# How to maintain empty directories recursively via Puppet

Tags: puppet

We have a puppet module which contains s class which creates a bunch of directories on a Linux filesystem:

```
class dim_dcm::dirstruct::workflow () {

  file { "/opt/dirstruct/etc":
    ensure  => 'directory',
    owner   => 'use',
    group   => 'group',
    mode    => '0640',
    recurse => true,
    purge   => true,
    source  => "puppet:///modules/dirstruct/etc",
  }
}
```

And we have a directory structure in the `files/` directory of our module. It works only when I create a directory with contents in `$module/file/dirstruct`. When the directory is empty, Puppet doesn't create the directory on the target server. When I touch a dummy file in the empty dir, Puppet is happy to do so.

How can I create empty directories with `recurse => true`? Yes, I know I could create a directory resource with that name, but the directory structures are rather involved. Besides, isn't creating directories (whether empty or not) the reason of `recurse => true`?

Comment: Sorry. Puppet wasn't really the cullprit. Seems that git isn't to smart for recognizing empty dirs at first hand. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository when you run into such a thing.